# Global conformal equivalence of two regions of Minkowski spacetime

Tags: differential-geometry, conformal-geometry, general-relativity, smooth-manifolds

I am wondering whether the region $H:=\{(t,x) : x^2-t^2<1\}$ of $(1+1)$-dimensional Minkowski spacetime, equipped with the restriction $g_H$ of the standard Minkowski metric $g=-\mathrm{d}t \otimes \mathrm{d}t + \mathrm{d}x \otimes \mathrm{d}x$, is globally conformally equivalent to the vertical strip $S:=\{(t,x):|x|<1\}$, again equipped with the restriction $g_S$ of the Minkowski metric. To further clarify: by "globally conformally equivalent" I mean that there should be a diffeomorphism $\phi:H \to S$ with $\phi_*(g_H)=\Omega^2 g_S$ for some smooth, strictly positive function $\Omega$.

I have the feeling that there might be an "obvious" reason why this is false, but the proof is escaping me at the moment. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I believe your feeling is well-founded: have a think about the behaviour of null curves.  I haven't thought it through fully but I think there might be something there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Anthony Carapetis indicated in his comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574593/global-conformal-equivalence-of-two-regions-of-minkowski-spacetime#comment1217461_574593), it suffices to think about null lines.

Consider the point $(0,0)\in H$. Let $\ell$ and $\bar{\ell}$ be the two null lines through $(0,0)$. It is easy to see that every maximally extended null-line in $H$ must intersect one of $\ell$ or $\bar{\ell}$ by simple plane geometry.

Fix any arbitrary point $s\in S$. Let $n$ and $\bar{n}$ be the two null lines emanating through $s$. It is easy to find maximally extended null lines that do not intersect either of $n$ or $\bar{n}$ (in $S$). For example, if the coordinate values of $s$ is $(x_s, t_s)$, then the two null lines through the point $(x_s, t_s + 10)$ would satisfy the criterion.

As conformal diffeomorphisms of 2 dimensional Lorentzian manifolds carry null curves to null curves, they must also carry their intersections to their intersections, and hence the above paragraph shows that there can be no conformal diffeomorphisms from $H$ to $S$.